# Android debugging DDMS failed connect Windows 8

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, windows-8, ddms

I have recently updated to **Windows 8**.

I can develop and run Android applications without any issues, but when it comes to debugging

I get the

**[2012-11-01 21:49:54 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8615 for debugger error.**

I've tried other solutions for this. Closing eclipse, killing instances, checking hosts file.. None of this has fixed anything !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that the problem is Java 7. I've tried to uninstall java 7, downgrading to java 6 and the android debugger, magically, started to work again.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to post back. I found that Java 6 solved my problem